# INDEX MATCH to search two different columns and return value

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, multiple-columns

I'm trying to write a formula that will return a value from another sheet. My Main Table has a list of project numbers that I need to fill in the assigned contractor name from another sheet. The problem is that there are two project numbers (categorized as `F1` & `F2`) on each row in different columns. I would like my formula to check both columns and return the contractor name.

In other words, my main table has both `F1` & `F2` project numbers on separate rows in the same column. My lookup table has the `F1` & `F2` numbers on the same row in two different columns.

Main Table `w` formula in column `O` - `F1` & `F2` numbers are in column `E`. Lookup Table has `F1` numbers in column `A`; and `F2` numbers in Column `B`. I want to fill in Column `O` with the Contractor Name that is in column `C` on the LookUp table. Here's what I have, but cant get it to work:

```
 =INDEX(JUW!$C$1:$C$51,MATCH(E2,JUW!$A$1:$A$51,0), MATCH(E2,JUW!$B$1:$B$51,0))
```

(`E2` is on a different sheet called `"Upload Report"` which is the sheet that has the formula in Column `O`.)

[Upload Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd9jy.png)

[JUW Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3utgw.png)

Answer (score 0):

use something like this, It uses an IF to determine which column to find the correct code:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E2,IF(F2="F1",A:A,B:B),0)),"Not Found")
```

[image]

So for yours:

```
=INDEX(JUW!$C:$C,MATCH(E2,IF(J2 = "F1", JUW!$A:$A,JUW!$B:$B),0))
```